# Using Ionic infinite scroll and YouTube v3 API

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, youtube-api

I am semi-successfully using ionic's [infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll/) and the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) to achieve pagination.

I am able to load the first 10 videos, then when I get to the end of my list, I can make one additional successful request to load the next 10 videos (totaling 20 videos on screen). After that, it seems like I am not properly updating the `nextPageToken` so nothing happens and I am just stuck with the spinning "loading data" icon.

Here is my `.ts` file that is handling the scrolling & showing the list of videos:

```
...

public videos: Array<any>;
public count = 10;
public pageToken: string;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.getPlaylistVideos();
}

// get the initial list of 10 videos 
// pass null for pageToken first time
async getPlaylistVideos() {
    console.log('getting initial video list');

    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    loading.present();

    this.youtubeService.getPlaylistVideos(environment.youtube.playlistId, this.count, null)
        .then(data => {
            loading.dismiss();

            if (data) {
                if (data.items) {
                    this.videos = data.items; // data.items is array of videos
                }
                if (data.nextPageToken) {
                    this.pageToken = data.nextPageToken;  // save the pageToken variable for next request
                }
            } else {
                this.alertCtrl.create({
                    header: 'Error',
                    subHeader: 'There was an error',
                    message: 'Something internet related happened & we couldn\'t load the playlist.',
                    buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', role: 'cancel' }]
                }).then(alert => {
                    alert.present();
                });
            }
        });
}
```

When I scroll to the bottom of my page, here is what I am doing to get more videos. This method will work *once*, but then seems to just get ignored.

```
loadMoreVideos(event) {
    console.log('--> loadMoreVideos called');

    if (this.pageToken) {
        // pass the pageToken to the service
  this.youtubeService.getPlaylistVideos(environment.youtube.playlistId, this.count, this.pageToken).then(data => {
            if (data) {
                this.pageToken = data.nextPageToken; // update the pageToken
                data.items.forEach(video => {
                    this.videos.push(video);  // add the incoming videos to the list
                });
            } else {
                this.alertCtrl.create({
                    header: 'Error',
                    subHeader: 'There was an error',
                    message: 'Something internet related happened & we couldn\'t load the playlist.',
                    buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', role: 'cancel' }]
                }).then(alert => {
                    alert.present();
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once the `loadMoreVideos` method loads the next 10 videos (I'll have 20 on screen at this point) it nolonger executes and I'm not sure why.

Here is what my youtube service looks like.

```
getPlaylistVideos(playlistId: string, count: number, pageToken: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
        if (pageToken) {
            console.log('incoming pageToken: ', pageToken);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.http.get(`${ environment.youtube.baseUrl }playlistItems?key=${ environment.youtube.apiKey }&playlistId=${ playlistId }&part=snippet,id&maxResults=${ count }&pageToken=${ pageToken }&order=date`)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        resolve(data);
                    }, error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('no page token');
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.http.get(`${ environment.youtube.baseUrl }playlistItems?key=${ environment.youtube.apiKey }&playlistId=${ playlistId }&part=snippet,id&maxResults=${ count }&order=date`)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        resolve(data);
                    }, error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error: something really bad happened trying to get the videos.');
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

I feel like I am very close, but just need a little push to get over the hump. Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are very close - you are getting the new `pageToken`. What it looks like you are missing the `event.target.complete();` at the end of your `forEach`.

This is what it should look like:

```
/**
 * Load more videos when scrolling.
 *
 * @param event
 */
loadMoreVideos(event) {
    if (this.pageToken) {
        this.myYoutubeService.getPlaylistVideos(environment.youtube.playlistId, this.count, this.pageToken).then(data => {
            if (data) {
                this.pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                data.items.forEach(video => {
                    this.videos.push(video);
                });
                event.target.complete();
            } else {
                this.alertCtrl.create({
                    header: 'Error',
                    subHeader: 'There was an error',
                    message: 'Something internet related happened & we couldn\'t load the playlist.',
                    buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', role: 'cancel' }]
                }).then(alert => {
                    alert.present();
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```